# JEST - Dummy wants to mock a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a script, that uses a function from another script. In my JEST test I don't want the other script to be included, but rather the function to return a default value.

Script to be tested

```
[...]
var session = getUser();    
[...]
```

TestScript

```
[...]
const getUser = jest.fn();
getUser.mockReturnValue({[...]});
[...]
```

As result I get

```
ReferenceError: getUser is not defined
> 21 |                      var session = getUser();
```

Comment: *I have a script, that uses a function from another script.* - what are those scripts and how exactly are they used in production? That you have this error suggests that these are vanilla browser scripts and don't use imports. You can mock getUser as window.getUser in this case.

Comment: Well, it's pretty much what you say.

I include 2 JS file in my HTML

script1.js contains the 

`function getUser() {
        [...]
    }`


script2.js calls it with a little bit of jQuery (document ready)

`$( document ).ready( async function() {
        var session = getUser();
    }`

I now want to unit test script2.js

I'm not sure about the syntax. I know ho to set a global variable

    `global.sAuthor = "Author 1";`

But how to set a function?

Comment: @EstusFlask Never mind. I found it! :-) Thanks for setting me on Track! (!!!)

   `global.window.getUser = jest.fn().mockReturnValue([...]);`

Answer (score 1):

Script to be tested

```
[...]
var session = getUser();    
[...]
```

TestScript

```
[...]
global.window.getUser = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({[...]});
[...]
```